# Kernel of a linear transformation: LCM or is it arbitrary as long as it satisfies kernel?

Tags: linear-transformations

A quick question for someone who is familiar with linear transformations.

If I've found the kernel of a linear transformation to be $\text{Ker}(t)=\{(k,2k,3k):k\in\mathbb{R}\}$, then would it be accurate to say it has a line through origin and $(1,2,3)$? (Assume for now the geometric transformation is a line). Would giving this vector be as appropriate as giving the vector $(4,8,12)$ or $(100,200,300)$? Is there a requirement for the given vector to be lowest common multiple, or is it arbitrary as long as it satisfies $\text{Ker}(t)$?

I have a question and I'm pretty confident I have everything correct, but there's an alternative answer that I'm supposed to critique that gives the vector $(4,8,12)$. Although it follows the parameters of the vector $(k,2k,3k)$ and is just a scalar multiple, are they both apt?

And if any scalar multiple of the vector is correct, couldn't I say $\text{Ker}(t)=\{(10k, 20k, 30k)\}$?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel doesn't *have* a line passing through the origin and $(1,2,3)$; it *is* the line passing through the origin and $(1,2,3)$. Any any non-null element of the kernel will do. It would also be fine (although weird) to state that the kernel is the line passing through the origin and $\left(-\frac\pi3,-\frac\pi2,-\pi\right)$.

Comment: So Ker t = {k, 2k, 3k} is just as valid as Ker t = {5k, 10k, 15k}?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}$